# Multiple sessions and WPPConnect

Tags: node.js

In my Node.js project, I have implemented a system that enables me to communicate with a server by sending commands through HTTP POST or GET requests. The server has been configured to listen on a particular port, allowing it to receive and process these commands. The integration with WhatsApp is facilitated by utilizing the WPPConnect library.

Initially, when I initiate a new session and establish a connection between my Node.js application and WhatsApp on my mobile device, the functionality works seamlessly. I can successfully send and receive messages, perform actions, and interact with the WhatsApp platform as intended.

However, my challenge arises when attempting to set up a second session within the application. Upon initiating the pairing process with a separate WhatsApp account on my phone, an unexpected error surfaces. The specific error message that is encountered during this second session setup is as follows:

> session.state: OPENING
> session.state: PAIRING
> session.state: CONNECTED
> Session status: inChat
> Session name:  axj
>
> HERE STARTING SECOND SESSION
>
> starting...sra
> session == false
> newSession.state: STARTING
> Session status: desconnectedMobile
> Session name:  sra
> Session status: notLogged
> Session name:  sra
> Session status: qrReadError
> Session name:  sra
> Session status: autocloseCalled
> Session name:  sra
> error:    [sra:client] Auto Close Called
> error:    Unhandled Rejection: "Auto Close Called"
> Session status: browserClose
> Session name:  sra
> TargetCloseError: Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
> at CDPSessionImpl.send (/root/myzapp/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:429:35)
> at ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (/root/myzapp/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:223:14)
> at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (/root/myzapp/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:197:107)
> at /root/myzapp/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:99:29
> at async ExecutionContext.convertArgument (/root/myzapp/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:269:19)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)
> at async ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (/root/myzapp/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:247:24)
> at async Frame.addScriptTag (/root/myzapp/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Frame.js:218:75)

It is worth noting that I have diligently stored the necessary tokens required for both sessions in my project. Despite having the tokens readily available, I have been unable to overcome this error and achieve the desired functionality for the second session.

Here is the index.js

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const Sessions = require("./sessions");
require('dotenv').config();

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({
    limit: '20mb',
    extended: true
}));

var appPort = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 3336;

if (process.env.HTTPS == 1) { //with ssl
    https.createServer({
            key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_KEY_PATH),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_CERT_PATH)
        },
        app).listen(appPort);
    console.log("Https server running on port " + appPort);
} else { //http
    app.listen(appPort, () => {
        console.log("Http server running on port " + appPort);
    });
} //http

app.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
    var result = {
        "result": "ok"
    };
    res.json(result);
}); //

app.post('/exec', async (req, res) => {
    const {
        stdout,
        stderr
    } = await exec(req.body.command);
    res.send(stdout);
});

app.get("/start", async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("starting..." + req.query.sessionName);
    var session = process.env.JSONBINIO_SECRET_KEY ?
        await Sessions.start(req.query.sessionName, {
            jsonbinio_secret_key: process.env.JSONBINIO_SECRET_KEY,
            jsonbinio_bin_id: process.env.JSONBINIO_BIN_ID
        }) :
        await Sessions.start(req.query.sessionName);
    if (["CONNECTED", "QRCODE", "STARTING"].includes(session.state)) {
        res.status(200).json({
            result: 'success',
            message: session.state
        });
    } else {
        res.status(200).json({
            result: 'error',
            message: session.state
        });
    }
}); //start

app.get("/status", async (req, res, next) => {
    var session = await Sessions.getStatus(req.query.sessionName);
    console.log(session);
    res.status(200).json({
        result: (!session.state) ? 'NOT_FOUND' : session.state
    });
}); //status

app.get("/qrcode", async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("qrcode..." + req.query.sessionName);
    var session = Sessions.getSession(req.query.sessionName);

    if (session != false) {
        if (session.status != 'isLogged') {
            if (req.query.image) {
                session.qrcode = session.qrcode.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
                const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(session.qrcode, 'base64');
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'image/png',
                    'Content-Length': imageBuffer.length
                });
                res.end(imageBuffer);
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({
                    result: "success",
                    message: session.state,
                    qrcode: session.qrcode
                });
            }
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                result: "error",
                message: session.state
            });
        }
    } else {
        res.status(200).json({
            result: "error",
            message: "NOTFOUND"
        });
    }
}); //qrcode

app.get("/close", async (req, res, next) => {
    var result = await Sessions.closeSession(req.query.sessionName);
    res.json(result);
}); //close

process.stdin.resume(); //so the program will not close instantly

async function exitHandler(options, exitCode) {
    if (options.cleanup) {
        console.log('cleanup');
        await Sessions.getSessions().forEach(async session => {
            await Sessions.closeSession(session.sessionName);
        });
    }
    if (exitCode || exitCode === 0) {
        console.log(exitCode);
    }

    if (options.exit) {
        process.exit();
    }
} //exitHandler 
//do something when app is closing
process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null, {
    cleanup: true
}));
//catches ctrl+c event
process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.bind(null, {
    exit: true
}));
// catches "kill pid" (for example: nodemon restart)
process.on('SIGUSR1', exitHandler.bind(null, {
    exit: true
}));
process.on('SIGUSR2', exitHandler.bind(null, {
    exit: true
}));
//catches uncaught exceptions
process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler.bind(null, {
    exit: true
}));
```

and here sessions.js

```
'use strict';
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const wppconnect = require('@wppconnect-team/wppconnect');
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = class Sessions {

    static async start(sessionName, options = []) {
        Sessions.options = Sessions.options || options; //start object
        Sessions.sessions = Sessions.sessions || []; //start array

        var session = Sessions.getSession(sessionName);

        if (session === false) { //create new session
            console.log("session == false");
            session = await Sessions.addSesssion(sessionName);
        } else if (["CLOSED"].includes(session.state)) { //restart session
            console.log("session.state == CLOSED");
            session.state = "STARTING";
            session.status = 'notLogged';
            session.client = Sessions.initSession(sessionName);
            Sessions.setup(sessionName);
        } else if (["CONFLICT", "UNPAIRED", "UNLAUNCHED"].includes(session.state)) {
            console.log("client.useHere()");
            session.client.then(client => {
                client.useHere();
            });
        } else {
            console.log("session.state: " + session.state);
        }
        return session;
    } //start

    static async getStatus(sessionName, options = []) {
        Sessions.options = Sessions.options || options;
        Sessions.sessions = Sessions.sessions || [];

        var session = Sessions.getSession(sessionName);
        return session;
    } //getStatus

    static async addSesssion(sessionName) {
        var newSession = {
            name: sessionName,
            hook: null,
            qrcode: false,
            client: false,
            status: 'notLogged',
            state: 'STARTING'
        }
        Sessions.sessions.push(newSession);
        console.log("newSession.state: " + newSession.state);

        //setup session
        newSession.client = Sessions.initSession(sessionName);
        Sessions.setup(sessionName);

        return newSession;
    } //addSession

    static async initSession(sessionName) {
        var session = Sessions.getSession(sessionName);
        session.browserSessionToken = null;


        const client = await wppconnect.create({
            session: session.name,
            catchQR: (base64Qrimg, asciiQR, attempts, urlCode) => {
                session.state = "QRCODE";
                session.qrcode = base64Qrimg;
                session.CodeasciiQR = asciiQR;
                session.CodeurlCode = urlCode;
            },
            statusFind: (statusSession, session) => {
                console.log('- Session status:', statusSession);
                console.log('- Session name: ', session);
            },
            folderNameToken: 'tokens',
            headless: true,
            devtools: false,
            useChrome: true,
            debug: false,
            logQR: true,
            browserArgs: [
                '--log-level=3',
                '--no-default-browser-check',
                '--disable-site-isolation-trials',
                '--no-experiments',
                '--ignore-gpu-blacklist',
                '--ignore-certificate-errors',
                '--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list',
                '--disable-gpu',
                '--disable-extensions',
                '--disable-default-apps',
                '--enable-features=NetworkService',
                '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                '--no-sandbox',
                // Extras
                '--disable-webgl',
                '--disable-threaded-animation',
                '--disable-threaded-scrolling',
                '--disable-in-process-stack-traces',
                '--disable-histogram-customizer',
                '--disable-gl-extensions',
                '--disable-composited-antialiasing',
                '--disable-canvas-aa',
                '--disable-3d-apis',
                '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
                '--disable-accelerated-jpeg-decoding',
                '--disable-accelerated-mjpeg-decode',
                '--disable-app-list-dismiss-on-blur',
                '--disable-accelerated-video-decode',
            ],
            disableSpins: true,
            disableWelcome: false,
            updatesLog: true,
            autoClose: false,
            createPathFileToken: true,
            waitForLogin: true,

        });
        wppconnect.defaultLogger.level = 'error'
        session.state = "CONNECTED";
        return client;
    }
    static async setup(sessionName) {
        var session = Sessions.getSession(sessionName);

        await session.client.then(client => {
            client.onStateChange(state => {
                session.state = state;
                console.log("session.state: " + state);
            });
            client.onMessage(async (message) => {
                var session = Sessions.getSession(sessionName);
                if (session.hook != null) {
                    var config = {
                        method: 'post',
                        url: session.hook,
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        data: message
                    };
                    await axios(config)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                } else if (message.body == "TESTEBOT") {
                    client.sendText(message.from, 'Hello\nfriend!');
                }
            });
        });
    } //setup

    static async closeSession(sessionName) {
        var session = Sessions.getSession(sessionName);
        if (session) {
            if (session.state != "CLOSED") {
                if (session.client)
                    await session.client.then(async client => {
                        try {
                            await client.close();
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log("client.close(): " + error.message);
                        }
                        session.state = "CLOSED";
                        session.client = false;
                        console.log("client.close - session.state: " + session.state);
                    });
                return {
                    result: "success",
                    message: "CLOSED"
                };
            } else { //close
                return {
                    result: "success",
                    message: session.state
                };
            }
        } else {
            return {
                result: "error",
                message: "NOTFOUND"
            };
        }
    } //close

    static getSession(sessionName) {
        var foundSession = false;
        if (Sessions.sessions)
            Sessions.sessions.forEach(session => {
                if (sessionName == session.name) {
                    foundSession = session;
                }
            });
        return foundSession;
    } //getSession

    static getSessions() {
        if (Sessions.sessions) {
            return Sessions.sessions;
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    } //getSessions

    static async getQrcode(sessionName) {
        var session = Sessions.getSession(sessionName);
        if (session) {
            //if (["UNPAIRED", "UNPAIRED_IDLE"].includes(session.state)) {
            if (["UNPAIRED_IDLE"].includes(session.state)) {
                //restart session
                await Sessions.closeSession(sessionName);
                Sessions.start(sessionName);
                return {
                    result: "error",
                    message: session.state
                };
            } else if (["CLOSED"].includes(session.state)) {
                Sessions.start(sessionName);
                return {
                    result: "error",
                    message: session.state
                };
            } else { //CONNECTED
                if (session.status != 'isLogged') {
                    return {
                        result: "success",
                        message: session.state,
                        qrcode: session.qrcode
                    };
                } else {
                    return {
                        result: "success",
                        message: session.state
                    };
                }
            }
        } else {
            return {
                result: "error",
                message: "NOTFOUND"
            };
        }
    } //getQrcode
}
```